# Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata

Tags: matrix, playa

I have a template which channel's custom fields do not use neither Matrix nor Playa, but the template debugger shows about 60-70 times:

> Calling Extension Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata Calling Extension
>   Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata

Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Playa and Matrix both use the `channel_entries_tagdata` extension hook to do their thing. Extension hooks are called whenever that particular hook runs in EE's process, regardless of whether they may be needed anywhere on that individual page load. In this case, I can only assume you're returning 60-70 individual channel entries in your template?

But they are just function calls which in this case will return very quickly having done nothing.